# MPC-BE fails to render files that MPC-HC renders

Tags: audio, streaming, media-player-classic

I am switching to a new computer. I have MPC-HC on my old computer, but I understand that version is deprecated, so I installed MPC-BE on my new computer instead. However, I find that MPC-BE cannot play some of the audio streams MPC-HC is able to play. For example, this stream for WBUR radio works fine on MPC-HC, but not on MPC-BE:

`http://audio.wbur.org/stream/live_mp3.m3u`

I am aware that I may need to go to Options and add some external filters, but I never had to do that with MPC-HC, and I don't know how. In MPC-BE, there are many external filter options – should I expect that one of them will enable rendering of m3u streams, and if so, how do I figure out which one?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: That’s just a regular HTTP stream though, nothing fancy…? It should work with any media player that offers any support for streaming media.

Comment: Okay so it appears MPC-BE simply cannot load M3U playlists (and possibly others) directly from the network. That’s all. Download it and it just works.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for doing that research. It sounds like MPC-BE is not the successor to MPC-HC that I thought it was, if it can't stream media the way MPC-HC could. I will look for a different media player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *original* developer of MPC-HC is no longer active, but [development continues at GitHub](https://github.com/clsid2/mpc-hc/releases). The current version, MPC-HC.1.9.7.34.x64, was released 22 Aug, 2020, and it can play m3u live streams (as can VLC, which might be a good choice on Linux). There's no reason to switch to MPC-BE, unless it has advantages for you.

BTW, mentioning your OS platform (e.g., Windows 10, Ubuntu, etc.) can help get a better answer.